# How to trigger a website on file creation?

Tags: windows

I want to create a task which triggers a website whenever a new file is created in a specific folder. Can anyone suggest how to do this on Windows (XP if possible) and Windows 7?

Thanks.

Comment: What is "trigger a website" supposed to mean?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I want to invoke the web browser to open a specific URL.

Comment: @Vj87 Is the file significant, or are you going to launch the exact same URL regardless of what file is created?

Answer (score 0):

You may use [Windows Task Scheduler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb756979.aspx) to schedule programs to run at a time you specify or when a specific event(Linked with event log) occurs.

Update :
You may need a custom program which writes a log entry to the event logs when a file creation event occurs in a specific folder.

Comment: Yes I am trying to use the Windows Task Scheduler, but I am not sure which Event log to check (to see a file has been created in a specific folder). Thanks.